# Parse 1.7.3 Crash reporting

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

Anyone experience a crash on

```
[ParseCrashReporting enable]
```

after the update to 1.7.3? Should I downgrade to 1.7.2 or hope and pray that a 1.7.4 update comes out soon?

Comment: post the complete error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK- Someone at Parse must have seen this post!

V1.7.4 — MAY 20, 2015

New: PFQueryTableViewController and PFQueryCollectionViewController in ParseUI now support dynamic deletion of objects.
Improved: Task-based PFFile APIs now support downloading a file with a progress block.
Improved: Error alert descriptions in all ParseUI components.
**Fixed: Crash when enabling ParseCrashReporting.**
Other small bug fixes.

Answer (score 2):

I got a same problem as below in Parse/ParseCrashReporting 1.7.3 version.

[image]

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: BreakpadMinidumpLocation)'

We seems to be downgrade to 1.7.2.2.

Comment: yes this is the exact error im getting! did downgrading fix your problem?